# How do I access the right child entites when I select a parent?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

This is one of those situations where I think I've solved my own problem but, being new to Cocoa (and programming in general), I'd like someone to check that I'm right!

My original problem was as follows: I have a simple CoreData program with a one-to-many relationship between two entities: "Categories" (parent) and "Checklists" (child). Tapping on a Category brings up a new view with a table of its Checklists. The problem was that if I tapped on one Category, I got a big list of all the Checklists from all the Categories - this list was the same no matter which category I tapped on.

My solution is to use a @property and a predicate. When I set up the Checklists view controller (in the Root View Controller's TableView:DidSelectRowAtIndexPath:) I did the following:

```
Category *category = (Category *)[__fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

detailViewController.category = category;
```

Then in the Checklist View Controller's fetchedResultsController method I did the following:

```
NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.name = %@", self.category.name];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];
```

This seems to have worked, but I just wanted to check I have gone about this in the right way. Thanks!

### -

EDIT - here's a screenshot of my Core Data model:
[image: Core Data Model]

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your coredata datamodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats OK. 
You could also get the sorted array using NSSortDescriptor :

`NSSortDescriptor *checkListName = [[NSSortDescriptor allo] initWithKey@"name" ascending:YES] autorelease];`

NSArray *sortedDescArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: checkListName, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: sortedDescArray];

All the best.